# Variable Boundaries on ParametricPlot3D

Tags: plotting

Is there any way to plot correctly using the `ParametricPlot3D` command with one of variable's boundaries defined in function of the other ?

In the example given here the variables are `u` and `r`.

- `r` boundaries are set from `0.01` to `d/2`
- `u` boundaries are set from the lower limit function `x0(r)` and upper limit function `corda(r)-x0(r)`

I noticed a problem on the leading edge of this wing profile present only when using a variable boundary, while if I use a constant boundary limit the wing is plotted correctly.

Any ideas on how to solve this problem? The code is presented below for reference.

```
c = 1;  e = 2;  d = 0.35;
(*Distribuição de Corda*)
corda[r_, c_] := c ( -30.04*r^3 + 4.65*r^2 + 0.116*r + 0.01)
(*Distribuição de Espessura*)
naca[r_, e_] := e ( -47.511*r^3 + 13.346*r^2 - 1.3953*r + 0.1511)
x0[r_, c_] := 0.4 corda[r, c]
(*Imagem do Perfil*)
FNaca[u_, r_, c_, e_] :=
    (naca[r, e]/0.2) corda[r,c] (  0.2969 Sqrt[(u + x0[r, c])/corda[r, c]] 
                                 - 0.126 (u + x0[r, c])/corda[r, c]
                                 - 0.3516 ((u + x0[r, c])/corda[r, c])^2
                                 + 0.2843 ((u + x0[r, c])/corda[r, c])^3 
                                 - 0.1015 ((u + x0[r, c])/corda[r, c])^4 )
m = 0.04;  p = 0.4;
(*Camber Bordo de Ataque*)
ba[u_, r_, c_] := m (u + x0[r, c]) ( 2 p - (u + x0[r, c])/corda[r, c])/p^2 
(*Camber Bordo de Fuga*)
bf[u_, r_, c_] :=
    m ((corda[r, c] - (u + x0[r, c]))/(1 - p)^2) ( 1 + (u + x0[r, c])/corda[r, c] - 2 p)
PerfilSup[u_, r_, c_, e_] := If[ u + x0[r, c] <= p corda[r, c],
                                 FNaca[u, r, c, e] + ba[u, r, c],
                                 FNaca[u, r, c, e] + bf[u, r, c] ]
PerfilInf[u_, r_, c_, e_] := If[ u + x0[r, c] <= p corda[r, c],
                                -FNaca[u, r, c, e] + ba[u, r, c],
                                -FNaca[u, r, c, e] + bf[u, r, c]]
d1[u_, r_, c_, e_] := PerfilInf[u, r, c, e]
f1[u_, r_, c_, e_] := PerfilSup[u, r, c, e]

ParametricPlot3D[{ {d1[u, r, c, e], u, r}, {f1[u, r, c, e], u, r}},
                   {r, 0.01, d/2}, {u, -x0[r, c], corda[r, c] - x0[r, c] } ]
```

Comment: You might want to look into `RegionFunction`...

Comment: @ThiagoMarihno What exactly is plotted incorrectly ?

Comment: Zooming in, the top and bottom surfaces don't join up very well, but I think that's just a sampling issue. Try setting the option `PlotPoints->100`. If that's not the problem, you will need to provide more detail in the question.

Comment: Simon, That's exactly the problem i'm having, thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this particular problem you could consider expressing everything in terms of `uu == (u + x0[r, c])/corda[r, c]` instead of `u`. The code then becomes something like

```
c = 1;  e = 2;  d = 0.35;
corda[r_, c_] := c ( -30.04*r^3 + 4.65*r^2 + 0.116*r + 0.01)
naca[r_, e_] := e ( -47.511*r^3 + 13.346*r^2 - 1.3953*r + 0.1511)
x0[r_, c_] := 0.4 corda[r, c]
m = 0.04;  p = 0.4;

FNaca1[uu_, r_, c_, e_] := ((naca[r, e]/0.2) corda[r, c] 
   (0.2969 Sqrt[uu] - 0.126 uu - 0.3516 uu^2 + 0.2843 uu^3 - 0.1015 uu^4))
ba1[uu_, r_, c_] := m corda[r, c] uu (2 p - uu)/p^2    
bf1[uu_, r_, c_] := m corda[r, c] (1 - uu)/(1 - p)^2 (1 + uu - 2 p)
PerfilSup1[uu_, r_, c_, e_] := If[uu <= p , FNaca1[uu, r, c, e] + ba1[uu, r, c], 
   FNaca1[uu, r, c, e] + bf1[uu, r, c]]
PerfilInf1[uu_, r_, c_, e_] := If[uu <= p, -FNaca1[uu, r, c, e] + 
   ba1[uu, r, c], -FNaca1[uu, r, c, e] + bf1[uu, r, c]]
d11[uu_, r_, c_, e_] := PerfilInf1[uu, r, c, e]
f11[uu_, r_, c_, e_] := PerfilSup1[uu, r, c, e]

ParametricPlot3D[{{d11[uu, r, c, e], uu corda[r, c] - x0[r, c], r},
   {f11[uu, r, c, e], uu corda[r, c] - x0[r, c], r}}, 
  {r, 0.01, d/2}, {uu, 0, 1},
  PlotPoints -> 30, MaxRecursion -> 3, BoxRatios -> {1, 3, 6}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: `uu` is a good idea, +1

Comment: @Heike, elegant solution. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

From documentation of [`ParametricPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ParametricPlot3D.html?q=ParametricPlot3D&lang=en) :

> You should realize that with the finite number of sample points used, it is possible for ParametricPlot3D to miss features in your functions. To check your results, you should try increasing the settings for PlotPoints and MaxRecursion.

and

> The default setting PlotPoints->Automatic corresponds to PlotPoints->75 for curves and PlotPoints->{15,15} for surfaces.

First, let's try to decrease the default number of `PlotPoints`, e.g. :

```
ParametricPlot3D[{{d1[u, r, c, e], u, r}, {f1[u, r, c, e], u, r}},
                  {r, 0.01, d/2}, {u, -x0[r, c], corda[r, c] - x0[r, c]}, 
                  PlotPoints -> {7, 7}, MaxRecursion -> 1, BoxRatios -> {1.1, 3, 6}]
```

[image]

This plot is even worse than it would have been if `PlotPoints` option hadn't been specified :

```
ParametricPlot3D[{{d1[u, r, c, e], u, r}, {f1[u, r, c, e], u, r}}, 
                  {r, 0.01, d/2}, {u, -x0[r, c], corda[r, c] - x0[r, c]}, 
                  BoxRatios -> {1.1, 3, 6}]
```

[image]

Choosing appropriately increased parameters of the options we can get plots of desired quality.  However with increased `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion` timings of rendering plots increase too, it may take even a few minutes.

```
ParametricPlot3D[{{d1[u, r, c, e], u, r}, {f1[u, r, c, e], u, r}},
                  {r, 0.01, d/2}, {u, -x0[r, c], corda[r, c] - x0[r, c]}, 
                  PlotPoints -> {300, 300}, MaxRecursion -> 6, BoxRatios -> {1, 3, 6}]
```

[image]

Trying another options to customize your plots, these guides would be interesting : [3D Graphics Options](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/3DGraphicsOptions.html)   and [Graphics Options & Styling](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/GraphicsOptionsAndStyling.html).

Comment: Thanks, Very helpfull. Will try it out now!

Comment: That indeed helped a lot, at first it was visually fine, but there are still some very small holes if you zoom in enough. The surface resolution was a lot better aswell but still not nearly as good and precise as a nurbs surface. Im considering making a .txt bot file to draw it on rhinoceros from a few discrete points.

Is there anyway to adjust a NURBS surface to these points on mathematica? All the plot commands seem to create meshes.

Comment: @ThiagoMarinho If you increse `PlotPoints` and/or `MaxRecursion` there shouldn't be any holes. Try `Mesh -> None` to get rid of unwanted mesh.

Comment: Have you tried `PlotPoints -> 300, MaxRecursion -> 6` ? In this case it yields a plot with no holes.

Comment: I've exported the plot to 3ds format and opened the mesh on rhinoceros, you can alway find the holes if you zoom in enough. With higher values on the points option i get a higher definition mesh. Im looking into alternatives to draw this profile correctly for numerical flow applications.